# Issues with DataFrame displaying Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on an assignment for a course and I'm running into an issue with my dataframe. I made the changes as they requested, but when I go to display my new dataframe, it just shows the headers.

These are the requirements of the assignment:

1. Load the data file using pandas
2. Check for null values in the data.
3. Drop records with nulls in any of the columns
4. Size column has sizes in kb as well as mb. To analyze you'll need to convert them to numeric

- the data set has M and K and "Varies with device" showing up in these columns so I removed them

5. Price field is a string and has $ symbol. Remove the $ symbol and convert to numeric.
6. Average rating should be between 1 nd 5 as only these values are allowed. Drop the rows that have a value outside this range.
7. For Free apps in the Type column, drop these rows.

#Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')

headers = pd.DataFrame(['App', 'Category', 'Rating', 'Reviews', 'Size', 'Installs', 'Type', 'Price', 'Content Rating', 'Genres', 'Last Updated', 'Current Ver', 'Android Ver'])

ds['Size'] = ds['Size'].replace("Varies with Device", np.nan, inplace = True)

ds =ds.dropna()

ds['Size'] = ds['Size'].str.replace("M", "", regex = True)
    
ds['Size'] = ds['Size'].str.replace("k", "", regex = True)

ds['Size'] = ds['Size'].astype(float)

ds['Installs'] = ds['Installs'].str.replace("+", '', regex = True)

ds['Installs'] = ds['Installs'].astype(int)

ds['Reviews'] = ds['Reviews'].astype(float)

ds['Price'] = ds['Price'].str.replace("$", "", regex = True)

ds['Price'] = ds['Price'].astype(float)

indexrating = ds[(ds['Rating'] >= 1) & (ds['Rating'] <= 5)].index

ds.drop(indexrating, inplace = True)

ds['Type']= ds['Type'].replace("Free", np.nan, inplace = True)

ds =ds.dropna()

display(ds)
```

#I was expecting for a new dataframe to display with the dropped rows

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything that ends by 'M' or 'k' or contains "Varies with device", remove all rows.

```
>>> df['Size'].str[-1].value_counts()
M    7466  # ends with 'M'
e    1637  # ends with 'k'
k     257  # for "Varies with device"
Name: Size, dtype: int64
```

Try with this version:

```
df = pd.read_csv(googleplaystore.csv)  # 1
df = df.dropna()  # 3
df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d)', expand=False).astype(float) * df['Size'].str[-1].replace({'M': 1024, 'k': 1})  # 4
df = df.dropna()  # remove nan from "Varies with device"
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.strip('$').astype(float)  # 5
df = df.loc[df['Rating'].between(1, 5)]  # 6
df = df.loc[df['Type'] != 'Free']  # 7
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                 App            Category  Rating Reviews     Size  Installs  Type  Price Content Rating            Genres       Last Updated Current Ver Android Ver
234    TurboScan: scan documents and receipts in PDF            BUSINESS     4.7   11442   6963.2  100,000+  Paid   4.99       Everyone          Business     March 25, 2018       1.5.2  4.0 and up
235                   Tiny Scanner Pro: PDF Doc Scan            BUSINESS     4.8   10295  39936.0  100,000+  Paid   4.99       Everyone          Business     April 11, 2017       3.4.6  3.0 and up
290    TurboScan: scan documents and receipts in PDF            BUSINESS     4.7   11442   6963.2  100,000+  Paid   4.99       Everyone          Business     March 25, 2018       1.5.2  4.0 and up
291                   Tiny Scanner Pro: PDF Doc Scan            BUSINESS     4.8   10295  39936.0  100,000+  Paid   4.99       Everyone          Business     April 11, 2017       3.4.6  3.0 and up
477                                       Calculator              DATING     2.6      57   6348.8    1,000+  Paid   6.99       Everyone            Dating   October 25, 2017       1.1.6  4.0 and up
...                                              ...                 ...     ...     ...      ...       ...   ...    ...            ...               ...                ...         ...         ...
10690                                       FO Bixby     PERSONALIZATION     5.0       5    861.0      100+  Paid   0.99       Everyone   Personalization     April 25, 2018         0.2  7.0 and up
10697                                        Mu.F.O.                GAME     5.0       2  16384.0        1+  Paid   0.99       Everyone            Arcade      March 3, 2017         1.0  2.3 and up
10760                                Fast Tract Diet  HEALTH_AND_FITNESS     4.4      35   2457.6    1,000+  Paid   7.99       Everyone  Health & Fitness     August 8, 2018       1.9.3  4.2 and up
10782                        Trine 2: Complete Story                GAME     3.8     252  11264.0   10,000+  Paid  16.99           Teen            Action  February 27, 2015        2.22  5.0 and up
10785                                   sugar, sugar              FAMILY     4.2    1405   9728.0   10,000+  Paid   1.20       Everyone            Puzzle       June 5, 2018         2.7  2.3 and up

[577 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I was so fixated on it, that I couldn't see this solution.